# PayPal Webhook HTTP header does not include webhook id

Tags: python, flask, webhooks, paypal-sandbox, payment

I'm getting the following header from the PayPal sandbox in Python/Flask:

```
request_headers = request.headers

print(request_headers)

Host: www.mysite.com
Content-Length: 1306
Accept: */*
Paypal-Transmission-Id: ****
Paypal-Transmission-Time: 2022-06-30T11:39:45Z
Paypal-Transmission-Sig: ****
Paypal-Auth-Version: v2
Paypal-Cert-Url: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-*****
Paypal-Auth-Algo: SHA256withRSA
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PayPal/AUHD-****
Correlation-Id: ****
Cal-Poolstack: amqunphttpdeliveryd:UNPHTTPDELIVERY*CalThreadId=0*TopLevelTxnStartTime=****Host=***
X-B3-Spanid: ***
Client-Pid: ****
X-Cloud-Trace-Context:***
X-Appengine-City: ?
X-Appengine-Citylatlong: 0.000000,0.000000
X-Appengine-Country: US
X-Appengine-Region: ?
Via: 1.1 google
X-Forwarded-For: ***,***
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

Unfortunately, there is no webhookId as decribed in the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/#link-messagesignature), nor a validation signature with this shape:

```
<transmissionId>|<timeStamp>|<webhookId>|<crc32>
```

Is it because of the sandbox environment? How can know if the payment comes from Paypal and is not a fraud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webhook id used for verification is not included in the header since if it was, it could be spoofed by someone delivering a malicious/fake webhook.

The webhook id is returned when you subscribe to webhooks via API or in the web interface, and can be looked up in [the REST APP management interface](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) (or queried via the list webhooks API as well)

Comment: Thanks, understood. So how do I know if the signature is a good one? Do I have to check the certification url at every transaction?

Comment: The signature can be checked for every webhook received, using the method described in the documentation

Comment: The documentation is very poor from my point of view. It barely explains how to build the CRC32 field for example.